# How to access the last Element of Observable<array[ ]> in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 with Angular 5 in order to create my project.
Following is the code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument  } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export interface Details {
  name: string;
  phone: number;
  pphone: number;
  id: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-student',
  templateUrl: './add-student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-student.component.css']
})
export class AddStudentComponent implements OnInit {

  private studentCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Details>;
  students: Observable<Details[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.studentCollection = db.collection<Details>('collectionName');
    this.students = this.studentCollection.valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

All I want to is to access the last json object which is stored in `students:Observable<Details[]>` 
Is there any of doing so? 
Sorry for any posting errors.

Comment: Did you try takeLast Rxjs operator?

Comment: No. I haven't used that. Can you please suggest me proper syntax for the same. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just the value

```
this.studentCollection.valueChanges().subscribe(details
                                  => console.log(details[details.length-1]))
```

If you need it as an observable

**Edit**: Added mergeAll() following Aluan Haddad's comment

```
lastStudent$ = this.studentCollection.valueChanges().mergeAll().takeLast(1);
```